# Some Help to prove $\|T^{-1}\|=\|T\|^{-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm trying to prove that given to Banach spaces $X,Y$, and a continuous linear transformation
$T:X\to Y$ with bounded inverse $T^{-1}:Y\to X$. Then,

$$\|T^{-1}\|=\|T\|^{-1}$$

I already  know that $\|T^{-1}\|\cdot\|T\|\geq 1$. Some help to conclude?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not true.

Here is an example with the Euclidean induced norm. Note that this norm is the **maximum** eigenvalue of $A^*A$, hence if we construct a diagonal example with eigenvalues of the form $\lambda$ and ${ 1 \over \lambda}$, then both $A$ and $A^{-1}$ will have the same norm.

Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} {1 \over 2} & 0 \\ 0 & 2  \end{bmatrix}$. Then $\|A\|_2 = 2$, $\|A^{-1}\|_2 = 2$.